# Emulation for ERB extention -%> for the purpose of unittests

Tags: ruby, rake, chef-infra, erb

I need to evaluate an ERB template, and then ensure it's a valid NGINX configuration file, but vanilla ERB doesn't allow the `-%>` directive.  How am I able to add that extension into my rakefile?

I've been able to replicate the problem in `irb` as so:

```
~ $ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'erb'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> var = "yeah"
=> "yeah"
irb(main):003:0> ERB.new(" <% if var == 'yeh' -%>
irb(main):004:1"    something
irb(main):005:1"    <% else -%>
irb(main):006:1"    something else
irb(main):007:1"    <% end -%>
irb(main):008:1" ").result binding #"
SyntaxError: (erb):1: syntax error, unexpected ';'
...concat " ";  if var == 'yeh' -; _erbout.concat "\nsomething\...
...                               ^
(erb):3: syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting $end
;  else -; _erbout.concat "\nsomething else\n"
       ^
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/erb.rb:838:in `eval'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/erb.rb:838:in `result'
    from (irb):3
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use the `-%>` syntax in ERB you need to set the [*trim mode* option to '-'](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html#method-c-new). This is the third option to the constructor, you will need to pass `nil` as the second (unless you want to change the `safe_level` from the default):

```
ERB.new(" <% if var == 'yeh' %>
    something
    <% else %>
    something else
    <% end %>
 ", nil, '-').result binding
```

Without this option the `-` is included in the generated Ruby script and gives you the syntax error when you try to run it.

Note that there is another eRuby processor, [Erubis](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/) which might have slightly different options (it can [still use this syntax](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/users-guide.06.html#topics-trimspaces)). This one is used by Rails. Check out the docs for more info.

Comment: Heh. Thanks for providing clarification. Apparently it *is* in standard ERB now. This is funny.

Comment: @DaveNewton looking at the docs, it seems it was added in Ruby 2.0. I guess people coming from Rails expected it so it was added.

Comment: Makes sense. I didn't think it used to be in ERB proper, but it's good to have actual facts.

Comment: @DaveNewton it looks like it was just the docs added in 2.0: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/4fa9e3307dd3b2cf3afea278a833a5d05ddb45de, the trim option goes back even earlier, to 1.8 I think: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/f8817c7262afd77028e7cb704e440b67a1104cb7

Comment: Oh, I had no idea--I think my original rememberings are either wrong, or from a pretty old version.